# How to pass values('how many' are known at runtime) to SQL query

Tags: java, mysql, arrays, list, arraylist

I have following java code in which String array i.e. list which is dynamic value known at runtime. I need to pass this value to query mentioned in string variable i.e. SQL.

```
List[] list = new Arraylist();

String SQL = "select * from Table_name where col_1 IN ("+list[1]+")" OR
"col_1 IN("+list[2]+")" ....... OR "col_1 IN("+list[n]+")";

List <Class_Name> systemtails = jdbcTemplateObject.query(SQL, new 
Class_Name_Mapper());
```

One way to do is enclosing following query in a loop, that makes query to execute more than once which in-turn affect performance.

```
String SQL = "select * from Table_name where col_1 IN ("+list[i]+")";
```

where i=1,2,3,4...n. All answers are welcomed and thank you in advance :).

PS : Query is just framed for question perspective in reality believe me it is very complex and big.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I understand your query is in a for loop like so:

```
For int I = 0; I  < list.size; I++ {
String SQL = "select * from Table_name where col_1 IN ("+list[i]+")";
List <Class_Name> systemtails = jdbcTemplateObject.query(SQL, new 
Class_Name_Mapper());
}
```

why not do this instead:

```
    String SQL = "select * from Table_name where col_1 IN (";
    For int I = 0; I  < list.size; I++ {
      SQL+=list[I];
      If(I != list.size -1){
        SQL+=","; 
      }else{
        SQL +=")";
      }
    }
    List <Class_Name> systemtails = jdbcTemplateObject.query(SQL, new 
    Class_Name_Mapper());
```

Comment: Very helpful tnx :)

Comment: Some databases have limits for the "in" set size. E.g. in Oracle you can pass 1000 values.

Comment: @wumpz yeah you r right that is reason i used below query using 'OR'.

String SQL = "select * from Table_name where col_1 IN ("+list[1]+")" OR
"col_1 IN("+list[2]+")" ....... OR "col_1 IN("+list[n]+")";

Comment: SQL length is also limited. So to overcome this, you could introduce an temp table with all this values and then do an inner join with this table. Using a temp table it would be only visible to the actual session.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you should use `PreparedStatement` to avoid being prone to SQL Injection.

To do that, I would use a for loop to build the `IN` condition

```
boolean first = true;
String inCondition = "(";
for(int i = 0; i < list.length; i++){
    if(first){
        first = false;
    } else {
        inCondition += ", ";
    }
    inCondition += ?;
}
inCondition += ")";

PreparedStatement ps = "select * from Table_name where col_1 IN " + inCondition;

int index = 1;
for(String val : list) {
    ps.setString(index++, val);
}
```

Comment: Very helpful tnx :)